# NDM files between servers using hadoop java

Tags: java, spring, unix, hadoop

I am trying to transfer/move a file residing in hadoop(hdfs) to a destination server using NDM. (between Hadoop to another server using ndm)

Is there a way to do this in Hadoop using NDM(Network Data Mover)? or does this need to do with a Java API? Thanks in advance.